# Assets/sucriptusu/movement/onflor.cs(23,13): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'zoom.upZoom'

Tags: c#

so I'm trying to get this code to run, but its asking something about static which I don't really get. any help would make me happy :).
basically I wanted to make it so every time you jump your jump height would be lower. 
and that error at the top came out which I honestly (even after searching a bit) have no idea what it means.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class zoom : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public float zoomSpeed = 5f;
    public float upZoom = 20f;
    public bool flor = false;
    public float jumpamount = 5f;
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Jump();
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, 0f);
        transform.position += movement * Time.deltaTime * zoomSpeed;
    }   
    void Jump()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && flor == true);
        {
            upZoom = (upZoom - jumpamount);
            gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0f, upZoom), ForceMode2D.Impulse);  
        }
    }
}
```

other one

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class onflor : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject mouseplayerreal;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        mouseplayerreal = gameObject.transform.gameObject;
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) 
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Guroundo")
        {
            zoom.upZoom = 20f;

        }
    }
    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
            if (collision.collider.tag == "Guroundo")
            {

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: the problem is that  `zoom` which you used in  `zoom.upZoom = 20f;` is not initalized (i.e. `zoom = new zoom()`) or something similar. it must either be initalized in the constructor or it must be a static variable.

Comment: C# != UnityScript. UnityScript is a JavaScript derivative created for Unity.

Comment: what exactly does initialised mean?

Comment: what exactly does initialised mean?
I am very new to c# and unity.

Comment: what exactly does initialised mean?
I am very new to c# and unity.

Comment: what exactly does initialised mean?
I am very new to c# and unity.

Comment: what exactly does initialised mean?
I am very new to c# and unity.